# Pickle is slow when pickling C++ objects even with the highest protocol

Tags: python, c++, serialization, boost, multiprocessing

I have 3 processes that will each create a large object, which takes about 6 seconds. However, when using getstate and setstate, copying them takes more than 60 seconds. Is there a way to make the pickling faster? The objects are python classes inherited from a C++ extensions with boost/python. I have tried using the highest protocol as suggested in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119053/how-to-change-the-serialization-method-used-by-the-multiprocessing-module) since apparently dill is faster than pickle partly because it uses the highest protocole (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697379/why-is-dill-much-faster-and-more-disk-efficient-than-pickle-for-numpy-arrays)), but it's not making any difference.

Here's the basic structure of the code, the pickle support for deque and vectors are implemented in another file and is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762997/pickling-a-vector-in-boost-python):

C++ base class:

```
class Base{
public:
    Base(int a, boost::python::object o);
    // attributes
    vector<Info*>* infos;
    deque<Foo*>* foos;
    int a;
    boost::python::object o;
    // functions
};
Base::Base(int a, boost::python::object o)){
    // assign args
    this->a = a;
    this->o = o;
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        this->infos->push_back(new Info(i,i));
    }
}
struct base_picke_suite : boost::python::pickle_suite {
    static boost::python::tuple getinitargs(Base const& base){
        return boost::python::make_tuple(base.a, base.o);
    }
    static boost::python::tuple getstate(boost::python::object obj){
        const Base& base = boost::python::extract<Base&>(obj)();
        return boost::python::make_tuple(base.infos, base.foos, obj.attr("__dict__");
    }
    void setstate(boost::python::object obj, boost::python::tuple state){
        Base& base = boost::python::extract<Base&>(obj)();
        base.infos = state[0];
        base.foos = state[1];
        boost::python::dict d = extract<dict>(obj.attr("__dict__"));
        d.update(state[2]);
    }
    static bool getstate_manages_dict() { return true; }
};
```

In the python class:

```
from Base import *
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, a, o):
        super().__init__(a, o)
        self.i = 1
        self.j = 2
    def __getinitargs__(self):
        return (self.a, self.o)
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (self.infos, self.foos, self.i, self.j, self.__dict__)
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.infos = state[0]
        self.foos = state[1]
        self.i = state[2]
        self.j = state[3]
        self.__dict__.update(state[4])
    __getstate_manages_dict__ = True
```

While everything compiles and runs, the picking is 2x slower than native python code. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: likely no. Longer answer: with self-contained code, people could help you profile/verify

Comment: would it be faster to use pickle.dumps and pickle.load or is that basically the same thing?

Comment: Sounds like the same? However, worth a  try. I'll help if I can repro the slowness